# Display output with awk without brackets

Tags: awk

I want my output to display in a certain way.

I have the code beneath but i want to display the dates without the [] on both sides:

```
icat -o 2048 someimage.E01 171 | grep /etc | awk '{print $1 "\t" $7 " \t" $4 $5 }' 

167.22.123.17   /home/me/file1  [13/Sep/2014:12:52:16-0400]
167.22.123.17   /home/me/file2  [13/Sep/2014:12:53:44-0400]
```

I want it to be displayed like:

```
167.22.123.17   /home/me/file1  [13/Sep/2014:12:52:16-0400]
167.22.123.17   /home/me/file2  [13/Sep/2014:12:53:44-0400]
```

I looked around on the internet but i can't find a solution that works. Some assistance would be great!

Comment: Your current and desired outputs are the same. I'm guessing that's just a copy-and-paste mistake.

Comment: Try adding `sub(/\[/, "", $4); sub(/]/, "", $5);` after `{` if your Field 4 contains `[` and Field 5 contains `]`. To remove all `[` or `]`s, use `gsub(/[][]/, "", $4)` and `gsub(/[][]/, "", $5)`.

Comment: can you present the output of `icat`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work:

```
icat -o 2048 someimage.E01 171 | awk -v OFS="\t" '/\/etc/{print $1,$7, substr($4,2) substr($5,1,length($5)-1) }'
```

And this could also work:

```
icat -o 2048 someimage.E01 171 | awk 'BEGIN{FS="[][[:blank:]]+";OFS="\t"}/\/etc/{print $1,$7,$4 $5 }'
```